# Why does the function prints the results of the last project only?

Tags: c++, pointers, nested, function-pointers

I am trying to create a function calculating the net present worth(NPW) of each project, the project which has the highest NPW will be our choice.

The program works fine for one project, if I enter more than one project it prints only the last project results repeated as much as the number of the projects.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void npwMethod(int nproj,int *pv,int *n, int *oc, int *ai,int *sv ,float marr){
    float npw[nproj], sum[nproj];
    
    for(int i=1;i<=nproj;i++){
        
        for(int j=1;j<=n[i];j++){
            sum[i]+=(oc[j]*(pow(1+marr,-j)));
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=n[i];j++){
            sum[i]+=(ai[j]*(pow(1+marr,-j)));
        }
        npw[i]=pv[i]+sv[i]*(pow(1+marr,-n[i]))+sum[i];
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=nproj;i++){
        cout<<"NPW"<<i<<"="<<npw[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int nProj,methodNum, *OC, *AI;
    float MARR;
    
    cout<<"Enter the number of projects please:";
    cin>>nProj;
    
    int *PV=new int[nProj], *N=new int[nProj], *SV=new int [nProj];     
    
    for(int i=1;i<=nProj;i++){
        cout<<"------Project"<<i<<"------\n";
        cout<<"PV"<<i<<":";
        cin>>PV[i];
        cout<<"n"<<i<<":";
        cin>>N[i];
        
        OC=new int[N[i]], AI=new int [N[i]];
        
        for(int j=1;j<=N[i];j++){
            cout<<"OC"<<j<<":";
            cin>>OC[j];
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=N[i];j++){
            cout<<"AI"<<j<<":";
            cin>>AI[j];
        }
        
        cout<<"SV"<<i<<":";
        cin>>SV[i];
                
    }
    
    cout<<"-------------------\nMARR:";
    cin>>MARR;
    MARR=MARR/100;
    
    cout<<"------RESULTS------\n";
    npwMethod(nProj, PV, N, OC, AI, SV, MARR);
}
```

Inputs:

```
Enter the number of projects please:2
------Project1------
PV1:-1000
n1:2
OC1:-200
OC2:-300
AI1:0
AI2:0
SV:2000
------Project2------
PV1:-1000
n1:2
OC1:-200
OC2:-300
AI1:500
AI2:0
SV:2000
-------------------
MARR:10
```

Expected output:

```
NPW1:223.14
NPW2:677.686
```

Could anyone help solving this issue please?

Comment: That's not valid C++ code.  Are you using a non-standard compiler extension?  If not, you should enable compiler warnings, fix the warnings, and see if that fixes the problem.  Also, in C++ the arrays start at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: You should consider using `std::vector` as variable length arrays are not always supported in C++. This also applies to avoiding `new[]` by using `std::vector` as well.

Comment: What is going on with `OC=new int[N[i]], AI=new int [N[i]];`?

Comment: What's going on with both `float npw[nproj], sum[nproj];`, non-standard C++, and `int *PV=new int[nProj]`, pointless use of pointers; that both are two completely different ways to do the same thing? This is an indication of search engine-based programming due to incomplete C++ domain knowledge: a cobbled-together program assembled from multiple search engine queries, and different sources, hoping that the end result works. Finally, array indexes in C++ start at 0, not 1. The shown code uses 1, resulting in memory corruption and undefined behavior.

Comment: @tadman These two variable are depending upon the number of N(num of years), therefore I am creating them as a dynamic.

Comment: What I'm pointing out is that reads as clutter. Break that up into two lines. Space things out. Give the variables names that mean something. While standards vary, most C++ code uses lower-case for variables, reserving upper-case for constants and classes. **Use `std::vector`** as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem boils down to these lines:

```
    int* OC;
    for(int i=1; i <= nProj; i++){
        OC = new int[N[i]];
        for(int j=1; j <= N[i]; j++){
            cout << "OC" << j << ":";
            cin >> OC[j];
        }
    }
    
    npwMethod(nProj, PV, N, OC, AI, SV, MARR);
```

with `OC = new int[N[i]]`, you override the value of OC from the previous project. Same happens for AI. You need your OC to be an array of arrays. This is a lot easier when you use `std::vector`. Then you could do something like this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> OCs;
    for(int i=1; i <= nProj; i++){
        OCs.emplace_back();
        OC = OCs.back();
        for(int j=1; j <= N[i]; j++){
            cout << "OC" << j << ":";
            int oc;
            cin >> oc;
            OC.push_back(oc);
        }
    }
    
    npwMethod(nProj, PV, N, OCs, AI, SV, MARR);
}

void npwMethod(..., std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& oc, ...) {
    for(int i=1; i<=nproj; i++){
        for(int j=1 ;j<=n[i]; j++){
            sum[i] += oc[i][j]*...;
        }
    }
}
```